# Python - Spelling test

Tags: python, testing, spelling

Hello everyone this is my first post and I've only been coding for about a week, my school teacher is also not the greatest at explaining things so be nice :) I'm trying to make a program that will display a definition of a word then the user will input what they think the word is.If they get it right they will be awarded 2 points, if they get 1 letter wrong then they will be given 1 point and if more than 1 letter is wrong then they will be given 0 points. in the future the user will have to login but i'm working on this part first. Any ideas how to get this to work?

```
    score = score 
definition1 = "the round red or green fruit grown on a tree and used in pies"
word1 = "apple"
def spellingtest ():
    print (definition1)
spellinginput = input ("enter spelling")
if spellinginput == word1
    print = ("Well done, you have entered spelling correctly") and score = score+100
```

Edit:  When i run it i get an invalid syntax error on this line

```
if spellinginput == word1
```

Comment: You'll get a better response if you can make your question a bit more detailed. What happens when you run your code, and how does the result differ from what you were expecting it to do?

Answer (score 0):

> If they get it right they will be awarded 2 points, if they get 1
>   letter wrong then they will be given 1 point and if more than 1 letter
>   is wrong then they will be given 0 points.

It's not as simple as you might be thinking. A single mis-spelling would mean,

1. Insertion of a single character `apple -> appple`
2. Deletion of a single character `apple -> aple`
3. Replacing a single character `apple - apqle`

Instead of writing your own algorithm to take all these, you need to off load the task to the expert [difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_opcode](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_opcodes)

It determines, the changes required to transform one string to another, and your Job is to understand and parse the opcodes and determine, if the number of transformation exceeds one.

**Implementation**

```
misspelled = ["aple", "apqle", "appple","ale", "aplpe", "apppple"]
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
word1 = "apple"
def check_spelling(word, mistake):
    sm = SequenceMatcher(None, word, mistake)
    opcode = sm.get_opcodes()
    if len(opcode) > 3:
        return False
    if len(opcode) == 3:
        tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 = opcode[1]
        if tag == 'delete':
            if i2 - i1 > 1:
                return False
        else:
            if j2 - j1 > 1:
                return False
    return True
```

**Output**

```
for word in misspelled :
    print "{} - {} -> {}".format(word1, word, check_spelling(word1, word))


apple - aple -> True
apple - apqle -> True
apple - appple -> True
apple - ale -> False
apple - aplpe -> False
apple - apppple -> False
```

Comment: Maybe instead of Levenshtein, also take into consideration the swapping of two adjacent letters as one single fault.

Comment: Thanks, remember i'm new and it's going to seem odd if i turn up to my lesson with this, how would i make it print "well done you are correct" if the input matches the correct spelling and "Wrong spelling, here is the correct spelling ..." if it does not match

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you want to keep it simple,

- Your first line:

  `score = score`

not sure what you want to achieve there, you should initialize to zero:

```
score = 0
```

- In your `if`statement

  `if spellinginput == word1`

you have a missing colon at the end.

- Your function

  `def spellingtest ():`

is supposed to print the definition but it is never called. Also, it uses a global variable, which is discouraged. It should be

```
def spellingtest (definition):
    print (definition)
```

Then you need to call it

```
spellingtest(definition1)
```

- Last line

  `print = ("Well done, you have entered spelling correctly") and score = score+100`

if you want to print that sentence and then increase the score you should write

```
print ("Well done, you have entered spelling correctly")
score = score + 100
```

otherwise you are trying to redefine `print` which is a reserved keyword. And `and` is used for the boolean operation AND, not to create a sequence of statements.

Comment: Thank you, now i get score is not defined

Comment: Thank you, it also wont print the definition. It just asks for the spelling